# Still trying to divide rectangles in multiple smaller ones. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

Dividing rectangles into smaller ones that would be used later as region of interests in some images.
Tried something like this (with your help):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


h = 330
w = 200
n_rows = 4
n_cols = 2

offsets = [(0, 0), (400, 0), (0, 500), (400, 500)]

blisters = []

image = cv2.imread('input.png')

for offset in offsets:
    pol = [(offset), (offset[0], offset[1] + h), (offset[0] + w, offset[1] + h), (offset[0] + w, offset[1])]
    blisters.append(pol)

offset_x = w / n_cols
offset_y = h / n_rows

pits = []
for offset in offsets:
    rectangles = []
    for x in np.linspace(offset[0], w, n_cols+1).tolist()[:-1]:
        for y in np.linspace(offset[1], h, n_rows+1).tolist()[:-1]:
            x1 = int(round(x))
            x2 = int(round(x + offset_x))
            y1 = int(round(y))
            y2 = int(round(y + offset_y))
            rectangles.append([[x1, y1], [x1, y2], [x2, y2], [x2, y1]])
    pits.append(rectangles)

np_pits = np.array(pits)

for pit in np_pits:
    cv2.polylines(image, pit, True, (0, 255, 0), 1)

np_blisters = np.array(blisters)

cv2.polylines(image, np_blisters, True, (0, 0, 255), 1)

print(np_blisters)
cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Or is there a way to use just the first array of rectangles and to somehow 'move' it?

and this is actuall result (red ones are 'original' rectangles to be divided):

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Easy! I just added in variables for `x_pos` and `y_pos` which will adjust the positioning.

I have included the updated code:

```
x_pos = 20
y_pos = 40

x1 = int(round(x + x_pos))
x2 = int(round(x + offset_x + x_pos))
y1 = int(round(y + y_pos))
y2 = int(round(y + offset_y + y_pos))
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. To put this lines of code in loop: 
    for y in np.linspace(offset[1], h, n_rows+1).tolist()[:-1]:
?

Comment: Put the x and y pos definitions outside the loop, up near the other definitions (h, w, offset). Replace the other four lines with those in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution if anyone interested:

```
for offset in offsets:
rectangles = []
for x in np.linspace(0, w, n_cols+1).tolist()[:-1]:
    for y in np.linspace(0, h, n_rows+1).tolist()[:-1]:
        x1 = int(round(x) + offset[0])
        x2 = int(round(x + offset_x + offset[0]))
        y1 = int(round(y) + offset[1])
        y2 = int(round(y + offset_y + offset[1]))
        rectangles.append([[x1, y1], [x1, y2], [x2, y2], [x2, y1]])
pits.append(rectangles)
```

just needed to add values from offset to x and y coordinates